# How I get access to it a module in the folder "/lib" in phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Say, I've created a module in the folder "lib" in my phoenix app. How can I get access to it from a controller, do I have to load it first? Or just alias? Or load on boot first and then alias?

Comment: Use it the usual way:  `MyApp.MyModule.some_func()`, you may alias or import it or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the modules in all the `.ex` (not `.exs`) files in `lib` are compiled into `.beam` files whenever you execute `mix compile` into `_build/dev/lib/my_app/ebin` where `dev` is the mix env and `my_app` is the app's name. Whenever you try to invoke a function on a module that's not already loaded, the Erlang VM searches for a corresponding `.beam` file in all the "code load paths" (which already contains `_build/dev/lib/my_app/ebin`) and if it finds one, loads it before executing the function. If it doesn't find one, you get a module not available error.

So, you don't have to load it. Just call the function and optionally alias if you want.